# Angular MSAL Library Concurrency Issues: msal-browser v3.2.0, Angular v16.2

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular, msal

I am a junior developer creating a angular library for use across all of my orginizations future angular applications. My issue is I am getting "uninitialized_public_client_application" when my handleRedirectPromise fires. I have been working on this issue for longer than I care to admit. I have seen some similar post but they haven't seemed to work and it being a library has added a bit of extra complexity.

This is my test applications app.module.ts:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgxSenateModule, MSAL_CONFIG_TOKEN, MsalAuthService } from 'ngx-senate';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SecondBestLayoutComponent } from './second-best-layout/second-best-layout.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export function msalInitializer(msalAuthService: MsalAuthService): Function {
  return () => msalAuthService.initialize();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    SecondBestLayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxSenateModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MSAL_CONFIG_TOKEN,
      useValue: environment.msalConfig
    },
    { 
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
      useFactory: msalInitializer, 
      deps: [MsalAuthService], 
      multi: true 
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the relevant part of my msal-auth.service.ts in my library, an error is triggered when calling handleRedirectPromise. The emitters here are for my auth-guard to make sure it does not try to start until the initialization of the msal service has completed. Please let me know if you need any farther information!

```
import { Injectable, Inject, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MSAL_CONFIG_TOKEN, MsalConfig } from './msal-config.token';
import {
  PublicClientApplication,
  LogLevel,
  AuthenticationResult,
  InteractionRequiredAuthError,
  Configuration,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MsalAuthService {
  private msalInstance?: PublicClientApplication;
  initialized = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(@Inject(MSAL_CONFIG_TOKEN) private msalConfig: MsalConfig) {
  }

  async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Initializing MSAL...");

    const msalConfig: Configuration= {
      auth: {
        clientId: this.msalConfig.clientId,
        authority: this.msalConfig.authority,
        redirectUri: this.msalConfig.redirectUri || window.location.origin,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: this.msalConfig.postLogoutRedirectUri || window.location.origin,
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
      },
      system: {
        loggerOptions: {
          loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
            console.log(message);
          },
          piiLoggingEnabled: false,
          logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
        },
      },
    };

    const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

    msalInstance
      .handleRedirectPromise()
      .then((tokenResponse) => {
        console.log("Msal Authenticated!");
        this.initialized.emit(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("MSal authentication failed.");
        console.log(error);
        this.initialized.emit(false);
      })
  }
```

Edit:
It seems that I needed to await the instance like this :

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfigSettings);
    await msalInstance.initialize();
```

Unfortunately my guard now gets stuck awaiting for the msalservice to emit a value here:

```
export const canActivate: CanActivateFn = async (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
  let config: AuthGuardConfig | null = null;
  try {
    config = inject(AUTH_GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN);
  } catch {
    console.log("No provider for AUTH_GUARD_CONFIG_TOKEN.")
  }

  const msalService: MsalAuthService = inject(MsalAuthService);
  // Ensure the MSAL service is initialized before proceeding.
  await firstValueFrom(msalService.initialized);
```

Edit 2:
This issue was due to an oversight on my part, the msal-service was using a const instance instead of a the class variable. Changing
`const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);`
to:
`this.msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);`
Fixed the issue.

Comment: This was solved, see the edits for the solutions that I found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Low-Signal for sharing the solution in Qs and comment. Posting it as an answer for the benefit of community:

The error message "uninitialized_public_client_application" indicates that the MSAL PublicClientApplication instance has not been initialized before calling the `handleRedirectPromise` method. This can happen if you call `handleRedirectPromise` before the `initialize` method has finished executing.

Using the below code, I am able to use the Angular MSAL Library:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  IPublicClientApplication,
  PublicClientApplication,
  BrowserCacheLocation,
  LogLevel,
  InteractionType,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import {
  MSAL_INSTANCE,
  MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
  MsalInterceptorConfiguration,
  MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
  MsalGuardConfiguration,
  MsalBroadcastService,
  MsalService,
  MsalGuard,
  MsalRedirectComponent,
  MsalModule,
  MsalInterceptor,
} from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

const GRAPH_ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';

const isIE =
  window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 ||
  window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

export function loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
  console.log(message);
}

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false,
      },
    },
  });
}

export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set(GRAPH_ENDPOINT, ['user.read']);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap,
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['user.read'],
    },
  };
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, ProfileComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]